# Is it okay to use “and” instead of “with”?

Tags: grammar

I was just wondering, is it okay to use the word “and” instead of “with” in these kinds of sentences?
For example, something like “Chimpanzees have a strong body *with* brown fur” is it okay to change the “with” to “and” so it becomes “Chimpanzees have a strong body *and* brown fur”?
Just because someone told me that using “and” is not correct and I should have used “with”.

Comment: 'I met a man with a speech impediment' would rarely have 'and' for 'with'. // 'The man had a stick with a brass head' is hardly synonymous with 'the man had a stick and a brass head'.

Comment: As illustrated by @EdwinAshworth above, "and" and "with" are not synonymous and thus cannot be interchanged willy-nilly. Doing so will subtly or drastically alter the meaning of the sentence. In your example, the shift is subtle--a chimp having a strong body *with* brown hair emphasizes the hair as a quality of the strong body rather than of the chimp. A chimp having a strong body *and* brown hair simply states two qualities of the chimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first instance describes one attribute, whereas using "and" describes two attributes of the chimpanzee. The difference lies in the meaning, so both could be correct.